# Game Identification: some air elemental called something like Zzyzzx

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing some customizable card game with a friend back sometime between ~1998-2004. I don't really remember much of anything about the game except that I think it was element based, and there was some lightning/air elemental called something like Zzyzzx. I've tried looking through the list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collectible_card_games) and googling variations of "Zzyzzx card game", but nothing is jumping out at me. It's possible it's on that list and I'm just not recognizing it.

Comment: Was the elemental perhaps called "Xyzzy", in tribute to [Colossal Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyzzy_(computing))? That doesn't help much because now you get lots of hits on Google instead...

Comment: There is
Zzzyxas's Abyss in Magic the Gathering https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74336

Comment: Incredibly [Wikipedia has a disambiguation page for this name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzyzx). Of note is the 1983 **video** game *Zzyzzyxx*, could that be it?

Comment: @Mosquite It was definitely not MTG. But it was magic-like.

Comment: @CainGoldhardt It was not a video game. It was a physical collectible card game. And it was definitely not called Zzyzzyxx. "Zzyzzx" or whatever the card was actually called was just the only card in the game I could come even close to remembering the name of.

Comment: @Cohensius I'm struggling to see the relevance of the image here?

Comment: I googled Zzyzzx and found about this road in California.  I think that the picture adds flavor to the question but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Cohensius Yeah, not sure it's relevant since I originally remembered the name of the card I had seen wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I found it via some more thorough browsing through a list of collectible card games. The game was [Magi-Nation Duel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi-Nation_Duel) which came out in 2000.

The creature card I was vaguely remembering was in fact called [Xyx](https://www.cardgamecollector.com/magi-nation-duel/single/xyx-arderial.html).
[image]